# How to set timeout of soapclient in .net core project

Tags: wcf, soap, asp.net-core-2.0, timeoutexception

I have to use a SOAP service in a .Net Core 2.0 project. I added service reference as described in following link: (*[Missing link, 404](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService)*)

Service is working fine for some methods. However, some methods are taking long time (due to the operations service is doing) and in this case the program is throwing  exception:"System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out"

I tried to set the timeout value but it has no effect.

```
MyService.MyServiceSoapClient Pr = 
    new MyService.MyServiceSoapClient(
            new MyService.MyServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration());

Pr.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

I also checked the folllowing link which has related questions about wcf/soap services in .Net Core: [GitHub: dotnet/wcf](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue%20label%3Atooling&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

But no solution so far. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok If anyone suffers from the same problem, I am posting the solution I found. It seems other people also faced this problem and asked question [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2368)

It is a generic error for .Net Core 2.0 as far as i understand and it occurs if request lasts longer than 30 seconds.

As can be seen in upper link, they posted a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/mconnew/0af8e688cedc32669a8e44a53fcbaa4a). It worked for me. Solution requires to make a fake request to service each time before making a real request so timeout settings can be changed. To avoid that I can suggest you to catch "CommunicationException", and apply the solution in that catch. So you make extra calls only if you really need to. I am copying the code, just in case link dies (all credits for code to https://github.com/mconnew/)

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new SimpleServiceClient();
        client.OpenAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        client.DelayedResponseAsync(2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var channel = client.InnerChannel;
        var httpChannelFactory = client.InnerChannel.GetProperty<IChannelFactory>();
        var cacheField = httpChannelFactory.GetType().GetField("_httpClientCache", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var httpClientCache = cacheField.GetValue(httpChannelFactory);
        var cacheDictionaryField = httpClientCache.GetType().GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        IDictionary cacheDictionary = (IDictionary)cacheDictionaryField.GetValue(httpClientCache);
        foreach(var cacheKey in cacheDictionary.Keys)
        {
            var cacheEntry = cacheDictionary[cacheKey];
            var valueField = cacheEntry.GetType().GetField("value", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            HttpClient httpClient = (HttpClient)valueField.GetValue(cacheEntry);
            FixHttpClient(httpClient);
        }

        client.DelayedResponseAsync(50000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void FixHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        var handlerField = typeof(HttpMessageInvoker).GetField("_handler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        DelegatingHandler delegatingHandler = (DelegatingHandler)handlerField.GetValue(httpClient); // Should be of type ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler
        WinHttpHandler winHttpHandler = (WinHttpHandler)delegatingHandler.InnerHandler;
        WinHttpHandler newHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
        newHandler.ServerCredentials = winHttpHandler.ServerCredentials;
        newHandler.CookieUsePolicy = winHttpHandler.CookieUsePolicy;
        newHandler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(winHttpHandler.ClientCertificates);
        newHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = winHttpHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
        newHandler.Proxy = winHttpHandler.Proxy;
        newHandler.AutomaticDecompression = winHttpHandler.AutomaticDecompression;
        newHandler.PreAuthenticate = winHttpHandler.PreAuthenticate;
        newHandler.CookieContainer = winHttpHandler.CookieContainer;

        // Fix the timeouts
        newHandler.ReceiveHeadersTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
        newHandler.ReceiveDataTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
        newHandler.SendTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

        var servicemodelHttpHandlerInnerHandlerField = delegatingHandler.GetType().GetField("_innerHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        servicemodelHttpHandlerInnerHandlerField.SetValue(delegatingHandler, newHandler);
        var delegatingHandlerInnerHandlerField = typeof(DelegatingHandler).GetField("_innerHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        delegatingHandlerInnerHandlerField.SetValue(delegatingHandler, newHandler);}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .Net7 I found this option

```
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```