# Dotnet Core - Self-contained very low performance when call Soap Service over WCF

Tags: performance, wcf, .net-core, soap, basichttpbinding

My context:

- I deploy an Dotnet core web API on Self Contained style (Stand Alone:Kestrel)
- My Application just call other Soap Webservice (Generated skeleton over svcutil 2.0.2)
- When I load test with about 50 threads (concurrent request), I  get a very high latency, requests blocked somewhere, I observe that it wait to open more and more Thread to receive request and open connection to Soap Webservice Endpoint
- This is not occur on IIS (using AspNetCoreModule)
- This is not occur when my application call database request
  I found some topic related to my issue but they cannot resolve it completly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wenlong/why-are-wcf-responses-slow-and-setminthreads-does-not-work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-scale-up-slowly
Could anyone can help

Important Note: This is application build on DotNet Core, Run on Kestrel, only call a Soap Service. Bad performance!

Thanks

Comment: You can read these WCF performance tuning articles to find a solution:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/wcf-performance-tuning/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/hh273113(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you, but articles you provide could not help me! They are not detail enough to implement
I still wonder why microsoft has release a product with this very critical issue. With this basic problem (call a soap service) we need to use something advanced to resolve as solution you mention.
This is the code that make the issue:
<code>var client = new MyService.MyServiceSoapClient (new MyServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration(),"address")'
client.MyTest();
</code>

Comment: Oneone can help. Thanks so much

Comment: You can try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079244/how-to-set-timeout-of-soapclient-in-net-core-project

Comment: @LanHuang: the link you provide is not relate to my issue (set timeout)